# Did cypress have solution like tags in robot framework

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, robotframework

I want to test some case in dev environment and test some case on production environment without separate test file, How can i do that?
I try to reseach about .skip but it seem like it not have condition like i just want to skip this case when run on production.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [cypress-grep](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-grep) plugin for this.

1. To install: `npm i -D cypress-grep`
2. Under `cypress/plugins/index.js` write:

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require('cypress-grep/src/plugin')(config)
  return config
}
```

3. Under `cypress/support/index.js` write:

```js
require('cypress-grep')()
```

Then you can run youer tests based on title sub-string or Tags:

```js
# run only the tests with "auth user" in the title
$ npx cypress run --env grep="auth user"
# run tests with "hello" or "auth user" in their titles
# by separating them with ";" character
$ npx cypress run --env grep="hello; auth user"
# run tests tagged @fast
$ npx cypress run --env grepTags=@fast
# run only the tests tagged "smoke"
# that have "login" in their titles
$ npx cypress run --env grep=login,grepTags=smoke
# only run the specs that have any tests with "user" in their titles
$ npx cypress run --env grep=user,grepFilterSpecs=true
# only run the specs that have any tests tagged "@smoke"
$ npx cypress run --env grepTags=@smoke,grepFilterSpecs=true
# run only tests that do not have any tags
# and are not inside suites that have any tags
$ npx cypress run --env grepUntagged=true
```

If you want to add tags in your tests, you can do like this:

```js
it('Test Case', {tags: 'regression'}, function () {})
describe('Test Suite', {tags: 'smoke'}, function () {})
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to check an environment variable and use `this.skip`

```js
it('only runs in development' function() {  // note function() here

  const isProduction = Cypress.env('test_env') === 'production';
  if (isProduction ) {
    this.skip();
  }

  // test here
})
```

There are four methods of setting the 'production' flag, see  [Cypress.env() - Setting](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Setting)

For example on the command line or `package.json` script

```js
cypress run --env test_env=production
```